# SQL*Plus does not run PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a problem running my PL/SQL script in SQL*Plus. I can run SQL commands normally but when I want to a run any PL/SQL code it gives nothing. See code and output below.

[image: screenshot]

```
DECLARE
    x_salary employee.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
    select salary
    into x_salary
    from employee
    where ssn=&enter_ssn;

    --Output the result
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary is ' || x_salary);

EXCEPTION
    --Output when no records are returned
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No employee found');

    WHEN others THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error encountered, but cause unknown');
END;
```

Comment: put a slash after semi-colon

Comment: after END ? or in the commande line?

Comment: in the command line.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - what do you mean by "in the command line"? The OP said this is a **script** - which means he is not running it interactively. The slash should come after END; on a new line, by itself.

Comment: thank you so much guys it did works

Comment: Not in command line, put the slash / after END; in a new line in your script.

Comment: while she's sharing a picture which suggests the script is in it. Did you see that @mathguy

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - ah, lol  -  no, I usually don't open images. But even so, the backslash rather belongs in the script, not after it... (I do see your point though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PL/SQL procedures needs `/` after procedure definition under sqlplus

```
DECLARE
 ...
BEGIN
 ...
END;

/
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put a slash `/` in a new line after `END;` in your script.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG446):

> You must include a semicolon at the end of each SQL command and a **slash (/)** on a line by itself after each PL/SQL block in the file.

Then execute the SQL file in SQL*Plus command line as:

```
@C:\your_script.sql;
```